# Is a Dragonborn's breath weapon an attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e

In 5e, is the breath weapon of a Dragonborn an attack action or can it be combined with another attack? The Player's Handbook does not specify.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about 5e? Since move actions and swift actions are both things in 3.5e that are not in 5e.

Comment: Also what breath weapon are you asking about? Since you mention the PHB I would guess the Dragonborn one, but I'm not sure

Comment: @K7AAY Since you ask if it can be combined with another attack, it's worth mentioning that a character could use his bonus action to make a completely separate attack if they are able based on their spells, equipment, or abilities. The bonus action would not be "combined," however.

Answer (score 6):

A [dragonborn's Breath Weapon](http://www.5esrd.com/races/dragonborn/) is an Action to use:

> **Breath Weapon:** You can use ***your action*** to exhale destructive energy. Your draconic ancestry determines the size, shape, and damage type of the exhalation.

In 5e there are no swift or movement actions. The "fast" action types are Bonus Action and Reaction. ([Movement is not an action type at all.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97278/explaining-the-move-action-in-5e)) So the breath weapon is just an Action, which is the rough 5e equivalent of the "standard action" you might be used to from other editions.